# Not able to setup Tomboy Web for Ubuntu One

Tags: 12.04, firefox, tomboy, sync

I have been trying to setup Tomboy Web in Ubuntu 12.04 but without much success.

I press the "Connect to Server" in the Preferences dialog and the expected result is for your browser to open, with the Authorization page.

But, in my case, Firefox opens but the authorization page does not open at all.

**Some details**:
My default browser is Chrome, but Firefox always opens that to with a non-default profile.

**Note**:
I have already browsed through most of the other articles in AskUbuntu regarding TomBoy Synchronization, but none of them discuss this particular problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is with Firefox and not with Tomboy Notes.

As explained [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202155/cant-load-webpages-from-applications), Firefox uses the `Exec` entry in the `.desktop` file to figure out which command to use to open links from external applications.

For our problem to be solved we just need to change this Exec entry to `firefox %u`.