# Can't load webpages from applications

Tags: firefox, browser

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, Firefox 16.0.01.

Whenever I try to open a webpage in a browser from within any application, the browser opens but nothing gets loaded.

For eg: From DropBox if I click `Launch DropBox Website`, Firefox opens but all I get is the Firefox Home Page.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting for some time, I finally figured out the problem.

Ubuntu somehow does not use the gconf key for handling URLs, but rather uses the `Exec` entry in the `firefox.desktop` file.

So change the Exec entry in your firefox.desktop to `firefox %u`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and execute these commands:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command --type string 'firefox %u'
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/https/command --type string 'firefox %u'
```

This command tells your file-manager to open links using firefox. %u basically stands for the url to be opened. You can read more about it [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html).

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, but am still faced with the same problem.

Comment: Type "firefox google.com" in termianl. Does it open the google page?Also I have modified my answer, please have a look at it first.

Comment: I've figured out a way to solve the problem. Check out my answer. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox updates as of late seem broken in Ubuntu. not sure if its a Mozilla issue or a Ubuntu issue. my guess if Mozilla, given the frequency of there updates.

recommended solution? reinstall Firefox completely. open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

then type:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

these 2 commands will wipe out Firefox, then reinstall it to the latest version. it resolved a lot of issues I had.

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall firefox ...`?

Comment: that will work, but purging guarantees a complete wipe of any configurations.

Comment: Oh, ok. Cool___